# SQL select rows in a JOIN with max value on a column

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I'm selecting values from 3 different tables to get an overview of some product orders.
Without `MAX`, no issues.

Here's the data I'm working with:

```sql
-- limited to first rows for the sake of the exemple
+------+---------------------+-------------------------------+-------+
| ID   | post_date           | order_item_name               | price |
+------+---------------------+-------------------------------+-------+
| 2348 | 2019-01-23 18:47:34 | product A                     | 18.9  |
| 2348 | 2019-01-23 18:47:34 | Product B                     | 4.5   |
| 2348 | 2019-01-23 18:47:34 | Product C                     | 50.5  |
| 2349 | 2019-01-23 21:59:04 | Product E                     | 26.5  |
| 2352 | 2019-01-24 07:41:12 | Product C                     | 50.5  |
+------+---------------------+-------------------------------+-------+
```

These are returned by the following SQL query.

```sql
SELECT 
    p.ID AS order_id,
    post_date,
    order_item_name,
    meta_value as price
FROM wp_posts AS p
JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items
ON p.ID = order_id
JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id
WHERE 
    post_type = 'shop_order' 
    AND post_status = 'wc-completed'
    AND meta_key = '_line_subtotal';
```

Now what I would like is get only the most expensive product from each order.
Obviously, just using the `MAX` function with `GROUP BY` returns one line per order, but the product name doesn't match the price.

```sql
SELECT 
    p.ID AS order_id,
    post_date,
    order_item_name,
    MAX(meta_value) AS price
FROM alpha_posts AS p
JOIN alpha_woocommerce_order_items
ON p.ID = order_id
JOIN alpha_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
ON alpha_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id = alpha_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id
WHERE 
    post_type = 'shop_order' 
    AND post_status = 'wc-completed'
    AND meta_key = '_line_subtotal'
GROUP BY order_id;
```

That returns the highest price but the `order_item_name`  column doesn't correspond to the given price.

```sql
+----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+-------+
| order_id | post_date           | order_item_name               | price |
+----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+-------+
|     2348 | 2019-01-23 18:47:34 | Product A                     | 50.5  | -- should be product C
|     2349 | 2019-01-23 21:59:04 | Product B                     | 26.5  | -- product b is 4.5, so it's clearly not matching (same for the following results)
|     2352 | 2019-01-24 07:41:12 | Product A                     | 60.9  |
|     2354 | 2019-01-25 07:43:36 | Product C                     | 23.1  |
|     2355 | 2019-01-26 19:59:31 | Product D                     | 79.9  |
+----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+-------+
```

I've managed to find exemples for one-table queries, but I'm helpless for this multi-join one.

Comment: please show us an example of your expected output, and ideally your attempt with `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless, and see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I'm using limit just to keep it brief here for SO. I'm working on the full dataset.

Comment: @LaurentS. edited like you suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected, aggregate functions work on one column without considering other columns, they are not filters.

That's why the `MAX` function returns the maximum value met in the designated column, but others column are not the ones that correspond to the max value selected (or any result of an aggregate function).

In order to select the matching columns based on the max value, we can use a `JOIN` query, in our case, joining both on `order_id` and `price`.

```sql
SELECT 
    ID, 
    post_date,
    wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_name,
    wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_posts
JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items
ON ID = order_id
JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id
JOIN (
    SELECT
        order_id,
        MAX(meta_value) as price
    FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items
    JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
    ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id
    WHERE meta_key = '_line_subtotal'
    GROUP BY order_id
) b
ON ID = b.order_id AND wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value = price
WHERE 
    post_type = 'shop_order' 
    AND post_status = 'wc-completed'
    AND meta_key = '_line_subtotal';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT p.ID AS order_id, post_date, order_item_name, oimmeta_value as price,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.ID ORDER BY (meta_value + 0) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM wp_posts p JOIN
           wp_woocommerce_order_items oi
           ON p.ID = oi.order_id JOIN
           wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim
           ON oi.order_item_id = oim.order_item_id
      WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order' AND
            p.post_status = 'wc-completed' AND
            wpm.meta_key = '_line_subtotal'
     ) x
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  This assumes that `meta_value` is a string so it needs to be converted to a number for sorting purposes.

Comment: It indeed produces the desired output, but could you elaborate what's going on with the `seqnum`?